# .Net 4 menu output as a flyout

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

in .Net 4 i'm using a menu apapter like so:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="mainNav" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
<asp:Menu DataSourceID="mainNav" runat="server" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" />
```

But it's outputting a flyout type menu - all the top level links are showing and have arrows next to them. Then when you rollover these the next level is shown.

How do i get rid of this and get back to having just a un-ordered list being output?

As an aside why on earth do Microsoft think things like this are a good idea? So we've gone from .NET 3.5 where navigation was output in table, making it necessary to use adapters to get an normal list and now we've got this.

Comment: Shame you felt the need to rant. It doesn't add anything to your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems there is no straight-forward solution to this question. Another Menu adapter will have to be written to get rid of the JS menu flyouts. My original question did include a bit of a rant, yes, but on reflection I don't think it was an un-warranted rant ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be because you're using an `asp:Menu` control - which renders popup content - instead of a control that displays content in a panel (like, say, a `TreeView`)?

I suspect your rant *is* unwarranted if you're using a control that explicitly renders the style you're complaining about.  It also seems like there is a fairly straightforward solution.